# Mocking auto generated model functions created using sequelize-auto package

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I have created my models using the [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) package and used them in my controllers

```
const sequelize = require('../database/db');
var models = require("../models/init-models").initModels(sequelize);

var User = models.User;

const controllerMethod = async (req,res,next) => {
    //calls User.findAll() and returns the results
}
```

I have called the `findAll` function of **User** model in one of my controller methods

I want to test my controller method using Jest and want to mock the `findAll` function to return an empty object.
I have imported my models in the test file and mocked the `findAll` function as follows,

```
//inside test case
            models.User.findAll = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
                return {}
            });
            const spy = jest.spyOn(models.User, "findAll")
            await controllerMethod(req, res,next);
```

My question is when I run the test case it runs the actual `findAll()` function inside the controller instead of the mocked `findAll()`
i.e. `findAll()` returns actual data instead of `{}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the issue with your code is some confusion on how `spyOn` works. Please see the documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) specifically the following:

```
Note: By default, jest.spyOn also calls the spied method. This is different behavior from most other test libraries. If you want to overwrite the original function, you can use jest.spyOn(object, methodName).mockImplementation(() => customImplementation) or object[methodName] = jest.fn(() => customImplementation);
```

What this is telling you is that `spyOn` actual calls the original method, not the mock implementation.

The way I would do this (and assuming you do not need to assert on how `findAll` is called) is not use `spyOn` at all but create a dummy `models` that is returned from `initModels`, which has your dummy `findAll` method on it. Something like the following:

```
const mockModels = {
        User: {
            findAll: jest.fn(() => {})
        }
    };
    // And then in your test - be careful as jest.mock is "hoisted" so you need to make sure mockModels has already been declared and assigned

test('blah', () => {
    jest.mock("../models/init-models", () => ({
        initModels: jest.fn(() => mockModels,
    });
    await controllerMethod(req, res, next) // ...etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I imported my models after the `jest.mock` and it would print `{}` when I `console.log(await models.User.findAll())` inside the test case , still the `controllerMethod` calls the actual `findAll`.

Comment: OK, how does the `controllerMethod` actually invoke that function?

Comment: inside a try block i have `const user = await User.findAll({where: {id: something}})` . I am later checking if `user.length != 0` to return my result, so i want to simulate `findAll` such that it returns an empty array (not an object oops)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix my issue until I come across a better solution. Have also created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/issues/560) as well

I created a seperate `models.js` file and exported all my Models via that. Imported Models to my Controllers from the `models.js` file instead of   `const sequelize = require('../database/db'); var models = require("../models/init-models").initModels(sequelize);`

`models.js`

```js
const sequelize = require('../database/db');
var models = require("./init-models").initModels(sequelize);

module.exports.User= models.User;
module.exports.Instrument = models.Instrument;

module.exports.sequelize = sequelize;  //exported this too since I have used sequelize.fn in some of my controllers
```

`userController.js`

```js
//const sequelize = require('../database/db');
//var models = require("../models/init-models").initModels(sequelize);

//var User = models.User;
const {User,sequelize} = require('../service/models');  //imported models this way

const controllerMethod = async (req,res,next) => {
    //calls await User.findAll() and returns the results
}
```

`userController.test.js`

```js
const {controllerMethod} = require('../../../controllers/user');
const {User,sequelize} = require('../../../service/models');

//inside test case
           jest.spyOn(User, "findAll").mockImplementation(() => {return Promise.resolve([])});
           await controllerMethod(req, res,next);
```

in this way `findAll` mocks the way I wanted and returns the expected `[]`